# Create random numbers that regress around a linear line?

Tags: javascript

I need to create 30 random numbers that **regress linearly** between x and y.
For example, for x=50 and y=100, I will get an array with 30 random numbers that start with 50, ends in 100.

This array doesn't have to go only up, **numbers can go up or down**, but still approach y(100) at the end **linearly**. The standard deviation can be max x%, lets say 5%.
(we can't just create random numbers and put 50 at the end, it should be linear regression)

I have this function with some feedback, but its not really good:

```js
function get_rand(from,to,length){
    var arr = []
    var linear = from
    var feedback = 0
    const step = ((to - from) / length )    
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++){
        const noise  =  step + (Math.random() * 1 * step)  -1*feedback
        feedback =  Math.random() < 0.75 ? 0 : -noise * (1.0+Math.random())
        linear += noise + feedback          
        arr.push(linear.toFixed(1))
    }
    console.log(arr)
}

get_rand(50,100,30)
```

The issue is that it will not finish exactly in y, it is also not linearly regressing at all.

Comment: I ran the code you provided, and it seems to do what you asked for. Would you mind clarifying how you want the code improved?

Comment: yea it will not finish exactly in y, it is also not linearly regressing at all:)

Comment: I tried to clarify your question to prevent it from closing. Please check it out and update if I misunderstood something. Also, I'd suggest to move your answer to the question itself unless it is definitive solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better version that is actually linear regression:

```
get_rand(from,to,length){
    var arr = []
    var linear = from
    var feedback = 0
    const std = 5
    const step = ((to - from) / length )  
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++){
        const max = std*linear/100
        const noise  =  -max+(Math.random() * 2*max)   
        const num = linear + noise  
        linear+=step        
        arr.push(num)
    }
    arr[length-1] = to
    console.log(arr)
    return arr
}
```

Where we are close enough to add the destination number at the end of the array without ruining the regression.